# box2d iOS soft bodies

Tags: ios, box2d

I try to use joints connections for a group of rigid bodies to emulate soft body behavior with Box2d. But sometimes my well-structured body become an unordered mess of particles connected in a very ridiculous way. This usually happen when a big body falls on my "soft body". How to prevent a "soft body" from becoming a mess ? How to maintain its original ordered structure? Perhaps there is a better trick to emulate soft body behavior. Could you please share it with me?

Comment: suppose adding bounding shape and preventing the shape from collisions with parts of other objects (by filter groups) may help

Answer (score 0):

I somehow faced the same issue when trying to create "soft balls" with cocos2d 3.x.

I ended up using several bodies linked with springs. The hard part was to fine-tune the rigidity of the springs so that the body did not "explode" when having collisions.

This might help you: http://2sa-studio.blogspot.com/2014/05/soft-bodies-with-cocos2d-v3.html

Though I still have instability issues with this current solution.